# DHT sensor with RGB LED

Tags: rgb, led, arduino-ide, temperature

I have a DHT11 that outputs temperature and humidity values. I'm trying to `Serial.print` the colour of the light based on the set temperature conditions. So far I only get `1`s and `0`s. How can I change these integer values to output string say `RED`, `GREEN` or `BLUE`? Is this possible or do I just need a `Serial.print("RED");` in each loop to get it done?

**Code**

```
#include <dht.h>

dht DHT;
#define DHT11_PIN A5

int redPin = 10; // Red LED,  connected to digital pin 10  
int grnPin = 9; // Green LED, connected to digital pin 9 
int bluPin = 8; // Blue LED, connected to digital pin 8  

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(redPin, OUTPUT);// Sets the pins as output for RGB LED  
  pinMode(grnPin, OUTPUT);  
  pinMode(bluPin, OUTPUT);  
}

void loop() {
  int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
  int t = DHT.temperature;
  int h = DHT.humidity;
  Serial.print("Temperature = ");
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print( "," );
  Serial.print("Humidity = ");
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print("\n");
  delay(60000);
  if((DHT.temperature < 26) && (DHT.temperature >= 23.2)) {
    // Writing the LED colour pins HIGH or LOW to set colours
    digitalWrite(redPin, HIGH);  // yellow
    digitalWrite(grnPin, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(bluPin, LOW);
  }
  if((DHT.temperature < 23) && (DHT.temperature > 20.2)) {
    digitalWrite(grnPin, HIGH); // green
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(bluPin, LOW);
  }
  if((DHT.temperature < 20) && (DHT.temperature > 17.2)) {
    digitalWrite(grnPin, HIGH); // aqua
    digitalWrite(bluPin, HIGH);
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
  }
  if(DHT.temperature <= 17) {
    digitalWrite(bluPin, HIGH); // blue
    delay(100);
    digitalWrite(grnPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redPin, LOW);
  }
  delay(1000);
  // Sensor shouldn't be read too frequently so delay of 1s
}
```

I will be grateful if I can get some help. Thanks!

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-3-rgb-leds/theory-pwm

Comment: @Brick I had gone through that link before posting my question. It doesn't address what I'm hoping to achieve. I need to print out the colour on the LED to serial monitor. Make sense?